# Tengo un problema 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll en C#

Tags: c#

Debo imprimir cada uno de los elementos que traigo a un GRID pero me genera ese error al entrar al ciclo si lo pongo en in try los imprime pero el programa no se cierra queda ejecutandoce en el background y debo cerrarlo matando el proceso

```
 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
        int pos = 0;
        bool a = true;
        while (a == true)
        {
// EL ERROR SALE EN ESTA LINEA
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
///----
            {
                a = false;
            }
            else
            {
                a = true;
            }
            r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            pos++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bueno entonces creo el problema esta en tu ciclo si dices que nunca termina el ciclo eso no es normal debes de ver porque nunca entra a tu condición para que salga del ciclo, y en segunda el error es porque tu arreglo esta fuera de los indices.

Comment: como hago para no estar fuera de los indices

Comment: Checando porque no termina tu ciclo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero modificar la manera en la que accedes a los registros del datagrid.

Puedes utilizar un ciclo for considerando la cantidad de registros que tiene el datagrid, por ejemplo:

```
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Podrias agregar otra condicion a tu `while` asi:

```
while (a == true && pos < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
```

Comment: No puedo usar .length en rows

Comment: Intenta con `dataGridView1.Rows.Count`

Comment: Excelente @alanfcm si sirve pero ahora el problema sale en esta linea
    r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
que es donde por cada fila que me traiga la consulta imprimo ese documento